# Conditional Probability Question (Prizes)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Forty 17- and 18-year old students are the only people present at a party.

Male 17 yr olds: 9

Male 18 yr olds: 13

Female 17 yr olds: 7

Female 18 yr olds: 11

In the Grand Draw, each of the forty students has an equal chance of winning one of two prizes. The first prize is a gift token. The second prize is a box of chocolates. No student may win more than one prize. Find the probability that the box of chocolates will be won by a 17 year old, given that the gift token is won by a 17 year old male student.

I tried using the formula P(A and B) / P(B):
Here's one attempt: [ (9/40) * (15/39) ]/ 16/40

I did a few other tries, trying different logic, but the answer should be 0.467. I'm very confused.

Comment: I think it should be 15/39, (your were almost right, but should have used P(B)=9/40). The book answer is equal to 7/15 which seems to be the answer to a different question alltogether.

Comment: What Jaap Scherphuis commented.  More specifically, normally, the chance would be (16/40).  However, one of the 17 year olds (a boy) is eliminated from consideration because he won the other prize, and no one is allowed to win both prizes.  Therefore, of the 39 candidates left, only 15 are 17 year olds.  Your instinct, which was probably influenced by the book's typo re the wrong answer, led you astray.  It led you to think that the solution was more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: The book's anwer is correct for the question "Find the probability that the box of chocolates will be won by a 17 year old **female**, given that the gift token is won by a 17 year old male student"

Comment: To the OP: what Henno Brandsma's comment is suggesting is that his explanation was intended by the person who composed the problem.  Possibly, but that means that the problem was **very poorly worded.**

Comment: whew! that makes sense! I've spent almost an hour on this. Thank you, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just skip to the second draw after the first has been won by a 17-year old male (so only 8 are left, and 15 17-year olds in total).

The chance of a 17 year old winning in this situation is just $\frac{15}{39}$ and not the answer in your text. That one also mystifies me.

In your attempt the right numbers are $P(B)=\frac{9}{40}$ and $P(A \text{ and} B) =  \frac{9}{40}\frac{15}{39}$ and would have given the same.